# (PHP) Probability of two random strings be same

Tags: random

I have this code for generating random strings

```
public function random_string($length = 5)
{
  $chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890';
  return substr(str_shuffle($chars),0,$length); 
}
```

So, is it possible that two generated strings can be same ?

In my case, there can be a maximum of `62P5` (using permutation) numbers of strings of `5 characters`.

But whats the possibility that the `10th` & `1000th` generated random strings be same ?

Comment: interesting math.. let me calculate

Comment: If you want to rely on the uniqueness of random strings they should have at least 128 bits (22 characters) and should be generated with a well seeded and good PRNG. Your strings are too short and from a bad and badly seeded PRNG.

Answer (score 4):

This is known as the birthday problem and can be solved by

```
$chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890';
$length = 5;
$numChars = strlen($chars);
$numberOfStringsGenerated = 50000;

print "numStringsGenerated: " . $numberOfStringsGenerated . "\n";
print "numChars: " . $numChars . "\n";
print "lengthOfString: " . $length . "\n";

$totalPerms = 1;
for ($ii=0; $ii<$length; $ii++) {
  $totalPerms *= $numChars - $ii;
}
print "totalPerms: " . $totalPerms . "\n";

$totalProbablity = 1;
for ($ii=0; $ii< $numberOfStringsGenerated; $ii++) {
  $totalProbablity *= ($totalPerms - $ii)/$totalPerms;
}

print "Probablity: ";
print 1 - $totalProbablity . "\n";
```

[Here is the codepad output](http://codepad.org/DQwJsa5p)

[Here is the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)

This calculation assumes that the PRNG for the `str_shuffle` is good enough for all permutations to be equally likely, which won't be exactly true, especially as the number of chars increases.

Comment: Perhaps go further. Apply the formula and generate a value for the probability, then explain that value. Then.. you have my permission to +1.

Comment: @christopher - i have shown the calculation explicitly and added a codepad link.

Comment: But you assume that the underlying PRNG is good, which is an invalid assumption in this case. For 5 characters the result might fit reality, but for more than that your code vastly underestimates the probability of collisions. The PRNG behind `str_shuffle` is seeded badly and sucks by itself, so I'd expect collisions when generation 100k outputs even if `length` is big.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously that is possible.
The right way to do this, is store already used strings in a database.

I use this in a system that generates a random session token that is stored at database.
Always that I generate a new random session token, i query for it in session table. If no results, OK, else, generate a new token.

The probability is very low, but not impossible, and everytime you insert new tokens at table, the probability of overwriting just grow.